# how to add configmap created from a .txt to a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap

I am trying to make a simple config map from a config.txt file:

```
config.txt:
----------
key1=val1
key2=val2
```

this is the pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
    env:
      - name: KEY_VALUES
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: keyvalcfgmap
            key1: key1
            key2: key2
```

by running  `kubectl create configmap keyvalcfgmap --from-file=<filepath>  -o yaml > configmap.yaml` and applying the created configmap, I supposedly can use it in a pod. the question is how? I tried adding it as a volume or calling it using `--from-file=` and even `envFrom` but the best I could get was that the volume just mounted the file itself and not the configmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `envFrom` like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: keyvalcfgmap        #<--------------Here
  restartPolicy: Never
```

or you can use configmap as `env` variables

```
env:
  - name: NAME
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: keyvalcfgmap        #<--------------Here
        key: key1
  - name: NAME
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: keyvalcfgmap       #<--------------Here
        key: key2
```

Comment: the first option mount the file itself. The second option gives me the following error:
```error: error validating "nginx-pod.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].env[0].valueFrom.configMapKeyRef): unknown field "key1" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMapKeySelector, ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].env[0].valueFrom.configMapKeyRef): unknown field "key2" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMapKeySelector, ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].env[0].valueFrom.configMapKeyRef): missing required field "key" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMapKeySelector]```